# удаление графической оболочки

Tags: linux, archlinux

Как снести графическую оболочку kde плазма со всеми зависимостями (5.9.1-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat, 17 Oct 2020 13:30:37 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: pacman -Rs plasma или pacman -Rsu plasma-meta?

Comment: :(( остался https://imgur.com/t8w8kYM.png

Comment: видимо нужно все таки добавить u.